# Targeting html label text with a css selector

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML, is it possible to target the text within a label with a CSS selector?

```
<fieldset class="sl">
    <legend>
        Text Inputs
    </legend>
    <label>
        Text Input:
        <input type="text" />
    </label>

    <label>
        Read-only Text Input:
        <input type="text" readonly value="this is read-only" />
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

So in the above, I want to target "Text Input" or "Read-only Text Input:" and set the width to align the textboxes left positions.

The only thing I can think of that works is to wrap the text within a span.

```
<label>
    <span>Text Input:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

With CSS selector:

```
fieldset.sl label span {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

FYI - I'm looking at having best of both worlds using CSS to switch between label on the same line and separate line above the input - without having to modify the html structure - only a tweak to the fieldset class, like the following which uses the text in the label wrapped in a span.

[image: Target achieve]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the only CSS properties that allow you to style pure text are mostly related to the [font manipulation, color and letter spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Fundamentals).

You have a couple of best practice solutions to achieve what you want.

- You can wrap each text within a `<span>`
- or you could use a much cleaner alternative which is by using the `<label>` tags to wrap the actual labels and use [the `for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) on the `<label>` element to relate it to its specific `input` field.

For the second example, instead of having this:

```
<label>
    <span>Text Input:</span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

you would end up with this:

```
<label for="textinput">Text Input:</label>
<input type="text" id="textinput" />
```

If you still wish to group each `input` with its respective `<label>` and maintain full control over the field groups, you can always wrap them in a `<div>` tag, like so:

```
<div class="field-group">
    <label for="textinput">Text Input:</label>
    <input type="text" id="textinput" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) here and make `label` a grid container. This way text of `label` will be wrapped in anonymous grid item.

From [CSS grid specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-items):

> Each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a [grid container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-container) is wrapped in an anonymous [grid item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item). However, an anonymous grid item that contains only [white space](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text/#white-space-processing) is not rendered, as if it were [`display: none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ruby-1/#propdef-display).

Demo:

```css
.sl label {
  display: flex;
}

.sl label {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="sl">
  <legend>
    Text Inputs
  </legend>
  <label>
    Text Input:
    <input type="text" />
  </label>

  <label>
    Read-only Text Input:
    <input type="text" readonly value="this is read-only" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
```